# message flow - end when broker is stopping

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I have an IIB message flow that runs for a few hours each evening, using a java loop to perform some actions once per minute.

During that time, if the multi-instance broker that the flow is running on fails over, the failover hangs until this message flow ends its processing (potentially hours later).

Is there any kind of hook I can use in Java to say "if the broker is stopping or failing over, then cancel this processing to let it happen"?

---

Edit

I have now tried the following code as a test, but even when a request is made to stop the execution group/flow, the booleans all remain as true

```
    Boolean egIsRunning = true;
    Boolean aIsRunning = true;
    Boolean msgFlowIsRunning = true;
    while (egIsRunning && aIsRunning && msgFlowIsRunning)
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        ExecutionGroupProxy e = ExecutionGroupProxy.getLocalInstance();
        egIsRunning = e.isRunning();
        ApplicationProxy a = e.getApplicationByName("SANDBOX.APP");
        aIsRunning = a.isRunning();
        MessageFlowProxy m = a.getMessageFlowByName("SANDBOX_MSGFLOW");
        msgFlowIsRunning = m.isRunning();
    }
```

So, I don't think the Integration API is going to help here? Or is there some ".isTryingToStop" method that I'm missing?

Comment: simonalexander2005 - A suggestion would be to use a external scheduler such as control-m to trigger your message flow in IIB. Control-m can call a script which starts your flow and then another script which stops your flow. You can have a timer node within the flow to trigger each minute to achieve whatever you do once per minute. Try not to keep scheduling logic of the message flow within the message flow to avoid the scenario you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to look at the [Integration API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/be43410_.htm).

From within your Java Compute Node you can connect with [BrokerProxy.getLocalInstance()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.cmp.doc/com/ibm/broker/config/proxy/BrokerProxy.html#getLocalInstance()) (don't forget to `disconnect()`, otherwise you will run out of memory eventually). Then I would try [MessageFlowProxy.isRunning()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.cmp.doc/com/ibm/broker/config/proxy/MessageFlowProxy.html#isRunning()) as an exit criteria for your loop.

Should `isRunning` not work, there are other options like [AdministeredObjectListener](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.cmp.doc/com/ibm/broker/config/proxy/AdministeredObjectListener.html) to figure out what is happening with your flow.